# htaccess redirection keeps one segment

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite url like /myapplication/argument1/argument2 to /api/index.php/argument1/argument2

File index.php will handles all url that start with /myapplication/

Currently my htaccess looks like :

```
RewriteRule ^applicationpreleveur/(.*)$ ./api/index.php/$1
```

It keeps "applicationpreleveur" on the url when I see

```
var_dump(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

I believe that only the segment between parenthesis will be preserved ?

My second question is how can I pass get or post data ?

Thanks you

Regards

Comment: The `REQUEST_URI` will always show exactly the path as it was specified in the original request, regardless of what internal redirection you do.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks, seems PATH_INFO contains what I want.